# Get an average per hour of the last 7 days of a gauge metric

Tags: promql

I have a gauge metric in Prometheus, let's say `queue_length`. I would like to end up with a list of averages *per hour* for the last 7 days.

I know how to get an average over the last hour; that's simply `avg_over_time(queue_length[1h])`. However, I don't understand how to do this for the last 7 days. I have found the ability to get multiple points in time over the last week, like `queue_length[7d:1h]`, but that will give me results at the specific resolution, not the average of the time series over that hour.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like `avg_over_time(queue_length[1h])[7d:1h]` if I understood correctly. This calculates 1-hour average over a 7-day period, at a 1-hour subquery resolution.

Note that the step will align the result values to a round hour.

Here is an example
Scenario 1: both instant and range queries are requested at a round minute. The first query's value is equal to the second query's last value.
[image]
Scenario 2: both instant and range queries are requested at a non-round minute. The range query's last value is shifted, accordingly. Both queries don't match in this case.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if I query `avg_over_time(queue_length[1h])` Prometheus gives me a different result on the last hour than `avg_over_time(queue_length[1h])[1h:1h]`. This really hurts my brains; can you explain how that works?

Comment: @BerryLangerak `query[1h:1h]` returns result on the last "round" hour, meaning at hh:00:00. Check out timestamp returned with result.

Comment: That's right. I edited the answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: @BerryLangerak, oh, and by the way solution from my answer with `step` doesn't automatically aligns to "round" values. Don't know if that's good or bad for your need, but it's different.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, things like range and resolution of query results are handled outside of promQL.

Endpoint `/api/v1/query_range` [provides](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) parameters `start`, `end`, `step`.

To get last 7 days with resolution of one hour you need to pass timestamp of 7 days ago as `start`, current timestamp as `end`, and `1h` as `step`.

Clients like Grafana uses those parameters to. Total range can be configure as range of dashboard, or relative range of panel. And `step` as *Min step* in query options.